# How can validate password and confirm password

Tags: javascript

I want to confirm password in regular expression so i decide to validate password and confirm password separately. But password and confirm password no match. Therefore how can rematches password and confirm password through the regular expression javascript?
Thank you.

```
// Validate password
if(upassid == "") {
    printError("passErr", "Please enter your Password*");
} else {
    var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/;
    if(regex.test(upassid) === false) {
        printError("passErr", "Please enter a valid Password!*");
    } else{
        printError("passErr", "");
        passErr = false;
    }
}


// Validate confirm password
if(unpassid == "") {
    printError("unpassErr", "Please enter your Password*");
} else {
    var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/;
    if(regex.test(unpassid) === false) {
        printError("unpassErr", "Please enter a valid Password!*");
    } else{
        printError("unpassErr", "");
        unpassErr = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: how about you add some snippet of code which you have tried and wasn't working with exact error ?

Comment: Ok  i will sent the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you checking reqex for confirm password(unpassid) after validating password(upassid)? Why not just compare `unpassid ==upassid` ?

```
if(upassid == "") {
    printError("passErr", "Please enter your Password*");
} else {
    var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/;
    if(regex.test(upassid) === false) {
        printError("passErr", "Please enter a valid Password!*");
    } else if(unpassid !=upassid){
        printError("passErr", "Confirm Password does not match!*");
    } else {
       printError("unpassErr", "");
       unpassErr = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems that you have both the password and the confirmed password in a variable. So, I don't think you need a regex to compare if they match. You could just do this:

```
if (upassid != unpassid) {
    printError("unpassErr", "Passwords don't match");
}
```

So, your code could look like this:

```
var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/;

if (upassid == "") {
    printError("passErr", "Please enter your Password*");
} else if (unpassid == "") {
    printError("unpassErr", "Please confirm your Password!*");
} else if (upassid != unpassid) {
    printError("unpassErr", "Passwords do not match!*");
} else if(regex.test(upassid) === false) {
    printError("passErr", "Please enter a valid Password!*");
} else{
    printError("passErr", "");
    printError("unpassErr", "");
    passErr = false;
    unpassErr = false;
}
```

I've simplified it a bit, since you don't need to check that both the password and the confirmation match your regex, you only need the password to match it and the confirmation to be equal to the password.

Comment: So whrere i can implement that code because i need password and confirm password to be equaly

Comment: I've edited my answer with some code that might be helpful. Please take a look